# AWS Cognito as Django authentication back-end

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto, django-authentication, amazon-cognito

Does it make sense to attempt to use AWS Cognito as a Django authentication back-end? What would be the advantages of doing so? What would be some challenges / problem areas?

Has anyone done any work in this direction?

Answer (score 6):

It depends a bit on what your goal is for it as a back end. Cognito Identity doesn't currently manage users or user registration...etc. It leverages public providers (e.g. Twitter, Facebook, Digits, Google, Amazon...etc.) to get AWS credentials to access other AWS resources.

What were you hoping to do with this backend?

EDIT: As is commented below, the new Cognito User Pools feature allows this to happen.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer makes it clear that this is not a good question, stemming from my poor understanding of what Cognito actually is, which you did help clarify :)

Comment: This recently changed.